# What do HardCoded annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, cdi, java-6, seam3

I want to know what do **@HardCoded** annotation.
I don't found any documentation when I search in Google.
Thanks.

Comment: Which package is this annotation class being imported from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound more like you misunderstood example/explanation (wouldn't know without resource you used). Check [Seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/annotations.html) if you need to know more about annotations.

Comment: yeah, I'm so sorry, it's a Qualifier annotation used in a project that I use. Thanks for help !